# C++ I/O stream text file to array issue

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

My code is supposed to read 16 lines from a text file, and passing them into an array of 4 Objects, each with 4 attributes. The problem im encountering is that while everything seems to work fine on passing the text details to the array, the 1st array element of the last object in the array is not the one supposed to be! I am really stuck!

My code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int CDsize;

class CD {
public:
    // constructors
    CD();
    CD(string arist, string title, int year, double price);

    // getter methods
    string getArtist() const { return this->artist; }
    string getTitle() const { return this->title; }
    int getYear() const { return this->year; }
    double getPrice() const { return this->price; }

    // setter methods - inline functions
    void setArtist(const string artist) { this->artist = artist; }
    void setTitle(const string title) { this->title = title; }
    void setYear(const int year) { this->year = year; }
    void setPrice(const double price) { this->price = price; }

    // option methods
private:
    string artist;
    string title;
    int year;
    double price;
};

/*Text menu option 1/*
void printallcds(CD MAX_CDS[])
{
     int d;
  for (d=0; d<=CDsize; d++)

  {
    cout << "CD Number : " << d << "/ Artist : " << MAX_CDS[d].getArtist() << "/
Title : " << cout << MAX_CDS[d].getTitle() << "/ Year of Release : " <<
MAX_CDS[d].getYear() << "/ Price : " <<
  cout << MAX_CDS[d].getPrice() << endl;
  }
}*/

int main() {
    CD MAX_CDS[3];
    int CDsize = (sizeof(MAX_CDS) / sizeof(MAX_CDS[0]));
    ifstream CDfile("mystock.txt");
    string data;
    int yeardata;
    double pricedata;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        getline(CDfile, data);
        MAX_CDS[i].setArtist(data);

        getline(CDfile, data);
        MAX_CDS[i].setTitle(data);

        getline(CDfile, data);
        stringstream yearstream(data);
        yearstream >> yeardata;
        MAX_CDS[i].setYear(yeardata);

        getline(CDfile, data);
        stringstream pricestream(data);
        pricestream >> pricedata;
        MAX_CDS[i].setPrice(pricedata);
    }

    CDfile.close();

    // testing
    cout << MAX_CDS[3].getArtist() << endl; // error !!!
    cout << MAX_CDS[3].getTitle() << endl;
    cout << MAX_CDS[3].getYear() << endl;
    cout << MAX_CDS[3].getPrice() << endl;

    return 0;
}

// constructors implementation
CD::CD() {}

CD::CD(string artist, string title, int year, double price) {
    this->artist = artist;
    this->title = title;
    this->year = year;
    this->price = price;
}
}
```

Comment: could u show how the file contents look like, at least a couple of rows?

Comment: Why are you declaring CD MAX_CDS[3]; with size 3?

Comment: Third time this week I seen a question where someone declares an array with one less than wanted. Just because indexing starts at 0 doesn't mean the size does as well.

Answer (score 2):

You only have space for 3 items in `MAX_CDS` (see `CD MAX_CDS[3];`), yet you're referencing the 4th item in your error.

```
MAX_CDS[3] // Actually represents the 4th item
```

Counting starts from 0 in C++.

So, to reference the 3rd item, in your case the *last* item, use `MAX_CDS[2]` or `MAX_CDS[CDSize-1]`.

```
cout << MAX_CDS[CDSize-1].getArtist() << endl;
cout << MAX_CDS[CDSize-1].getTitle() << endl;
cout << MAX_CDS[CDSize-1].getYear() << endl;
cout << MAX_CDS[CDSize-1].getPrice() << endl;
```

Rereading your question, you probably want more items!

```
CD MAX_CDS[4]; // Now you have 4 items available: indexed 0, 1, 2, and 3
```